# Trigger Jenkins on commit on specific branch of github repo

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have two branches "main" and "develop" on github repo. I have configured my Jenkins pipeline as per the requirement using jobs-configuration.groovy file and it is stored on main branch only. Now, I want to setup my configuration in a such a way that any change in only the develop branch should trigger the Jenkins Pipeline. Please let me know, how this can be achieved.

I am not familiar with how the checkoutSCM settings works for another branch.